# Can't cast from Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment to SupportMapFragment

Tags: xamarin.android, supportmapfragment

I'm in a strange situation where I cannot cast a Fragment to a SupportMapFragment. And I've read the 8+ threads about similar problems, which are all not linked to my problem. They all mixed MapFragment and SupportMapFragment, or referenced Android.App instead of Android.Support.V4.App.

I'm in Mono (MvvmCross). My layout is containing a SupportMapFragment.

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

So, here's how I try to get my SupportMapFragment from my layout:

```
var theMap =  (SupportMapFragment) SupportFragmentManager
                                  .FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.map);

Cannot cast expression of type 'Android.Suport.V4.App.Fragment'
to type 'SupportMapFragment'
```

SupportMapFragment inherits from `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, so that's why I find it strange.

I have `Mono.Android.Support.v4` and `Xamarin.Android.Support.V4` referenced.

I noticed that my SupportFragmentManager comes from `global::Android.Support.V4.App` and not the previously mentionned two assemblies.

My project targets API 13 to 19, and compiles in API 19.

I'm using a precompiled version of Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Fragging as the version in the component doesn't build.

In short: what I get from `SupportFragmentManager` cannot be casted to `SupportMapFragment`.

Answer (score 0):

While I'd prefer not to answer my own problem, this issue is so problematic that I'll contribute in documenting workaround. To get it working, I:

- Added GooglePlayServices component
- Added Android Support V4 component
- Added original source code of Cirrous.MvvmCross.Droid.Fragging
- Made sure I only add Xamarin.Android.Support.V4 referenced and not Mono.Android.Support.V4

It now works without any assembly redirection.